# Surely there must be a cleaner way to do this

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I am building a bot that can display some statistics.

I get this response from an API:

```
"lifeTimeStats": [
{
  "key": "Top 5s",
  "value": "51"
},
{
  "key": "Top 3s",
  "value": "69"
},
{
  "key": "Top 6s",
  "value": "120"
},
{
  "key": "Top 10",
  "value": "66"
},
{
  "key": "Top 12s",
  "value": "122"
},
{
  "key": "Top 25s",
  "value": "161"
},
{
  "key": "Score",
  "value": "235,568"
},
{
  "key": "Matches Played",
  "value": "1206"
},
{
  "key": "Wins",
  "value": "49"
},
{
  "key": "Win%",
  "value": "4%"
},
{
  "key": "Kills",
  "value": "1293"
},
{
  "key": "K/d",
  "value": "1.12"
}
],
```

Here is my code to format this JSON:

```
def __getitem__(self, items):
    new_list = []
    new_list2 = []
    new_list3 = []
    new_list4 = []

    for item in self.response['lifeTimeStats']:
        for obj in item.items():
            for object in obj:
                new_list.append(object)

    for item in new_list[1::2]:
        new_list2.append(item)

    for item in new_list2[::2]:
        new_list3.append(item)

    for item in new_list2[1::2]:
        new_list4.append(item)

    result = dict(zip(new_list3, new_list4))

    return result[items]
```

The result is this:

```
{
'Top 5s': '1793',
'Top 3s': '1230',
'Top 6s': '1443',
'Top 10': '2075',
'Top 12s': '2116',
'Top 25s': '2454',
'Score': '4,198,425',
'Matches Played': '10951',
'Wins': '4077',
'Win%': '37%',
'Kills': '78836',
'K/d': '11.47'
}
```

I am happy with the result, and all I was just thinking is if there is a better way to format this? A cleaner way?

I am learning at the moment and I was gonna check if anyone have some thoughts on this.

This is how I get info after this:

```
f = Fortnite('PlayerName')
f['Matches Played']
```

Comment: *"better"* or *"cleaner"* how, exactly? What are you planning to use this data for, does it make sense to be machine readable, human readable, both?

Comment: Final product of this is that you can ask the bot for stats of a specific fortnite player and he will return this data. I havent done that part yet but i want a dictionary so i can easily get data by key. And cleaner, i was thinking that the use of 6 for loops is unessecary maybe?

Comment: Working code should be posted to Code Review

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple dict comprehension to iterate over the results, i.e.:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return {x["key"]: x["value"] for x in self.response["lifeTimeStats"]}[item]
```

That being said, why would you iterate over the response all the time whenever you want to retrieve a particular item? You should cache the result and then just access it as a normal dict.

Alternatively, since you're only interested in one key, you can just do:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    for stat in self.response["lifeTimeStats"]:
        if stat["key"] == item:
            return stat["value"]
```

Comment: Okey. That makes sense. because it would be better to be able to access a few more keys. So maybe i should run this function with the initiation of the class instead and store it in a variable then access the variable instead?

Comment: @Daniel - Yep, pretty much - whenever your `self.response` becomes available (or updates) store the results as, for example, `self.stats = {x["key"]: x["value"] for x in self.response["lifeTimeStats"]}`, and then you can just forward the cached results in the `__getitem__()` method as: `return self.stats[item]` .

Comment: Okey Thank you there was something like this i was looking for.